# Change background color of text when pressing a push button

Tags: matlab, button, callback, textbox, matlab-figure

Below is an image of my GUI:

[image]

When we press green push button under 'a', the background of the static text 'a' should turn red. How to do this?

Comment: Please provide the GUI code. Do you want to change the font color or the background color?

Comment: background colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function which does the following

```
set(txt,'BackgroundColor',[1 0 0]);
```

where txt is the handle for the static text. Then call this function from the callback on the button.

```
doc uicontrol
```

has all the details